# Why is my user-defined function producing static outputs in my ShinyApp?

Tags: r, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

I am trying to create a ShinyApp that randomises clinical trial participants using co-variate adaptive randomisation methods. This means that:

- The shinyApp takes input from three variables
- uses simple random sampling to choose the first treatment arm allocation
- for successive allocations (rows of user defined data) attempts to minimise the difference between treatment arms on each of the three variables.

**Problem**
I have written a user-defined function that takes the dynamic data.table (increasing as user adds more participants) and calculates the difference between treatment arms in terms of the three variables, then suggests the treatment arm allocation that achieves the best minimisation of difference.
However, when the ShinyApp is deployed, the function appears to be producing a static answer with every additional line of data, suggesting that it is not accepting as input to the function the dynamically updating data.table.

Below is the code (apologies that it is quite long). Any assistance would be greatly appreciated! (first time poster by the way).

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("industry", "Select Industry:",
        choices = c("White-collar", "Blue-collar")
      ),
      selectInput("industry_size", "Select Industry Size:",
        choices = c("Less than or equal to 150", "More than 150")
      ),
      selectInput("sex", "Select Sex:",
        choices = c("Less than or equal to 50% Female", "More than 50% Female")
      ),
      numericInput("seed", "Set Seed:", value = 1234),
      actionButton("randomize", "Randomize"),
      #actionButton("reset", "Reset")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      h3("The randomisation sequence is..."),
      tableOutput("number")
    )
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  mydata <- data.table(
    Industry_type = character(),
    Industry_size = character(),
    Sex_prop = character(),
    Allocation = character()
  )

  data <- eventReactive(input$randomize, {
    if (input$industry != "" && input$industry_size != "" && input$sex != "" && input$randomize > 0) {
      allocation <- function(x) {
        treatment_arms <- c("tau", "online")

        tmp <- data.frame(
          industry = ifelse(x$Industry == "Blue_collar", 0, 1),
          industry_size = ifelse(x$Industry_Size == "Less than or equal to 150", 0, 1),
          sex = ifelse(x$Sex == "Less than or equal to 50% Female", 0, 1),
          allocation = ifelse(x$Treatment_Arm == 2, "tau", "online")
        )

        tmp <- data.frame(
          industry = c(1, 0),
          industry_size = c(0, 1),
          sex = c(1, 1),
          allocation = c("tau", "online")
        )

        tmp[nrow(tmp), 4] <- "online"

        tot_1 <- with(tmp, sum(c(industry, industry_size, sex)[allocation == "tau"])) 
        tot_2 <- with(tmp, sum(c(industry, industry_size, sex)[allocation == "online"]))

        diff_1 <- diff(c(tot_1, tot_2))

        tmp[nrow(tmp), 4] <- "tau"

        tot_1 <- with(tmp, sum(c(industry, industry_size, sex)[allocation == "tau"])) 
        tot_2 <- with(tmp, sum(c(industry, industry_size, sex)[allocation == "online"]))

        diff_2 <- diff(c(tot_2, tot_1))

        alloc <- ifelse(diff_1 + diff_2 == 0, sample(c("tau", "online"), 1, replace = TRUE),
          ifelse(diff_1 + diff_2 > 0,
            ifelse(tmp[1, 4] == treatment_arms[1], "online", "tau")
          )
        )

        tmp[nrow(tmp), 4] <- alloc 

        df <- tmp

        return(df[nrow(df), 4])
      }


      alloc <-
        ifelse(nrow(mydata) < 1,
          sample(x = c("tau", "online"), 1, replace = TRUE),

          # Randomly assign treatment arms while minimizing distance between variables

          allocation(cbind(mydata$industry, mydata$industry_size, mydata$sex))
        )

      newrow <- data.table(
        Industry_type = input$industry,
        Industry_size = input$industry_size,
        Sex_prop = input$sex,
        Allocation = alloc
      )
      mydata <<- rbind(mydata, newrow)
    }
    mydata
  })

  output$number <- renderTable({
    data()
  })
})
shinyApp(ui, server)
```